# Tableview not receiving signals from Driver

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift, frp

I have the following MVVM-C + RxSwift code.

The problem is that the TableView is not receiving any signals. When I 
debug the results I can see that the API call is returning what it should, the `objects` array is populated with objects but the tableview does not show any results. Here is the console output:

```
2018-11-13 16:12:08.107: searchText -> Event next(qwerty)
Search something: qwerty
2018-11-13 16:12:08.324: viewModel.data -> Event next([])
```

Could it be the tableview itself? Maybe wrong custom cell setup?

**ViewController.swift:**

```
    tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.frame)
    tableView.delegate = nil
    tableView.dataSource = nil
    tableView.register(SearchResultCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SearchResultCell")

    viewModel.data
        .debug("viewModel.data", trimOutput: false)
        .drive(tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "SearchResultCell")) { row, object, cell in

            cell.name.text = object.name
            cell.something.text = object.something
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

**ViewModel.swift:**

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
var searchText = BehaviorRelay(value: "something to search for")

lazy var data: Driver<[Object]> = {
    return self.searchText.asObservable()
        .debug("searchText", trimOutput: false)
        .throttle(0.3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .flatMapLatest(searchSomething)
        .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])
}()

func searchSomething(query: String) -> Observable<[Object]> {

    print("Search something: \(query)")

    let provider = MoyaProvider<APIService>()

    var objects = [Object]()

    provider.rx.request(.search(query: query)).subscribe { event in
        switch event {
        case let .success(response):
            do {
                let responseJSON: NSDictionary = try (response.mapJSON() as? NSDictionary)!
                objects = self.parse(json: responseJSON["results"] as Any)

            } catch(let error) {
                print(error)
            }

            break
        case let .error(error):
            print(error)
            break
        }
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    let result: Observable<[Object]> = Observable.from(optional: objects)

    return result
}
```

Comment: From the debug output, the view model's resulting data is an empty array. Is this intentional?

Comment: No, that seems to be the issue actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When using `flatMap`, you do not want to create nested subscriptions. You will create an `Observable` that returns the expected result, and flatMap will take care of subscribing to it. In the current state of things, `searchSomething` will always return an empty array, as `Observable.from(optional: objects)` will be called before the request has a chance to complete.
- Since version 10.0 of Moya, provider will [cancel the requests it created when deallocated](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/issues/1558). Here, it will be deallocated when execution exits `searchSomething`, hence the network request won't have time to finish. Moving provider's declaration to the view model's level solves this issue.

Here's `searchSomething(query: String) -> Observable<[Object]>` rewritten.

```
let provider = MoyaProvider<APIService>()

func searchSomething(query: String) -> Observable<[Object]> {

    print("Search something: \(query)")

    return provider.rx.request(.search(query: query)).map { (response) -> [Object] in
        let responseJSON: NSDictionary = try (response.mapJSON() as? NSDictionary)!

        return self.parse(json: responseJSON["results"] as Any)
    }
}
```

Instead of doing the transformation in subscribe, it's done in `map`, which will be called for every `next` event, being passed the value associated with the event.

Comment: Great! But how about if I want to map the objects directly in the request, like this: .map([Object].self, atKeyPath: "results", using: decoder, failsOnEmptyData: true) ? It returns PrimitiveSequence<RxSwift.SingleTrait, Swift.Array<Project.Object>>>, how can I convert it to Observable<[Object]> ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Maybe it's worth posting a different question for this, with more detail.

Comment: The result of .map {} is 'PrimitiveSequence<SingleTrait, [Track]>', so I get: Cannot convert return expression of type 'PrimitiveSequence<SingleTrait, [Track]>' to return type 'Observable<[Track]>'

Comment: Add `.asObservable()`. Moya's `request` method returns a `Single` (a specialisation of Observable with guaranty that at maximum one next event will be emited). Swift cannot implicitely convert from `Single` to `Observable`.

Comment: Great - now `searchSomething()` does not give errors. But in the return of the data variable, the code execution stops at `.flatMapLatest(searchSomething)`, which means that `.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])` is not called.

Comment: No compiler errors - app builds but never gets past the `.flatMapLatest(searchSomething)` point.

Comment: If app builds, `.asDriver` **is** called, otherwise `data` could not return the expected type. I would advise adding a `debug` statement after `flatMapLatest` to make sure no error occurs in the chain, which might be the reason nothing is shown within the table view.

Comment: I did exactly that and the `debug` statement after `flatMapLatest` is not called, nor is the `debug` statement after `asDriver`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183619/discussion-between-tomahh-and-blackbeard).